NextJs 14 useShoppingCart and Stripe how to redirect to stripe checkout page after click button
I got error after click button function here is my code.
page.js
    const { cartCount , cartDetails ,formattedTotalPrice ,clearCart , redirectToCheckout } = useShoppingCart();

const onCheckOut = async () => {
        if (cartCount > 0) {

            try {
                setIsRedirecting(true)
                const { id } = await axios.post('/cart/api/checkout-sessions' , cartDetails) // ดึงค่า id ออกมา
                .then((res => res.data))
            
                const result = await redirectToCheckout(id)
                    if(result.error){
                        console.log('Error in result' , result);
                    }

            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error to redirect" , error);
            } finally {
                setIsRedirecting(false)
            }
            
        }
    }
add to button

and here my Api for Fetch to get redirect.
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === "POST") {  //รับข้อมูลที่ส่งมาจาก cart(cartDetails)
      try {
        const cartDetails = req.body;
const inventory = await stripe.products.list({
          expand: ["data.default_price"],
        });
        const products = inventory.data.map((product) => {
          const price = product.default_price;
          return {
            currency: price.currency,
            id: product.id,
            name: product.name,
            price: price.unit_amount,
            image: product.images[0],
          };
        });
        const lineItems = validateCartItems(products, cartDetails); //ตรวจสอบ cartDetails match กับ products กี่อันแล้วแสดงออกมาใน session
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({ //สร้าง
          mode: "payment",
          payment_method_types: ["card"],
          line_items: lineItems,
          success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`, //สำเร็จไปหน้านี้ต่อ
          cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/cart`, //กลับหน้า cart
        });
        res.status(200).json(session);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: error.message });
      }
    } else {
      res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
      res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
    }
  }

and I got this error. I try to check but my code is normal but I can't go another page after click button.
page.js:26 POST http://localhost:3000/cart/api/checkout-sessions 405 (Method Not Allowed).
Error to redirect AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 405', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}.
